# React Native - Identify the active screen. Drawer navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I am using stack navigator inside the drawer navigator. What I want to do is, I need to know the activeItem (the active screen), so as to display it as active.

> StackNavigator

```
const stackNav = StackNavigator({
  homeComponent: { screen: HomeScreen },
  serviceScreen: { screen: ServiceScreen },
  serviceDetailScreen: { screen: ServiceDetailScreen },
  selectVehicleScreen: { screen: SelectVehileScreen },
  addEditVehicle: { screen: AddVehicle },
  dateTimeScreen: { screen: DateTimeScreen },
  reviewScreen: { screen: ReviewScreen },
  notesScreen: { screen: NotesScreen },
}, {
  headerMode: 'none'
});
```

> DrawerNavigator

```
const DrawerStack = DrawerNavigator({
  appointment: {
    screen: stackNav,
  },
}, {
  headerMode: 'none',
  gesturesEnabled: false,
  contentComponent: DrawerContainer

});

export default DrawerStack;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is

In your context there is only one screen that can be active and that is appointment screen.
If you want to know that if appointment screen is focused then you should check the props inside the DrawerContainer Component. It will give you the `activeItemKey` i.e appointment.

And then you can simply check in `DrawerComponent` that if

```
this.props.activeItemKey === 'appointment' ? { color: '#000' } : { color: '#fff' }]}
```

You can also pass the `activeTintColor` prop from DrawerNavigator as shown below
You can find other `DrawerNavigatorConfigs` [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator.html)

```
const DrawerStack = DrawerNavigator({
  appointment: {
    screen: stackNav,
  },
}, {
  headerMode: 'none',
  gesturesEnabled: false,
  contentComponent: DrawerContainer,
  contentOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
    itemsContainerStyle: {
        marginVertical: 0,
    },
    iconContainerStyle: {
        opacity: 1
    }
  }
});

export default DrawerStack;
```